# Join multiple children with DocumentDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to run the following query on DocumentDb

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM p JOIN filter IN p.Filters
WHERE filter.Id = "686e4c9c-f1ab-40ce-8472-cc5d63597263" 
AND filter.Id = "caa2c2a0-cc5b-42e3-9943-dcda776bdc20"
```

My json is like this

```
 {
    "id": "a3dc570b-26e2-40a9-8777-683186965f78",
    "Filters": [
      {
        "Id": "686e4c9c-f1ab-40ce-8472-cc5d63597263"
      },
      {
        "Id": "caa2c2a0-cc5b-42e3-9943-dcda776bdc20"
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to find the entities that has a child Filter with Id "686e4c9c-f1ab-40ce-8472-cc5d63597263" and a child Filter with Id "Id": "caa2c2a0-cc5b-42e3-9943-dcda776bdc20", however the query returns no results.

If I use OR instead of AND I can get results, but that's obviously not the results I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For querying across multiple children within a single parent - you could use multiple `JOINS`.

**Note:** this can potentially become an expensive query due to having to perform multiple cross products.

```sql
SELECT p.id
FROM p
JOIN filter1 IN p.Filters
JOIN filter2 IN p.Filters
WHERE filter1.Id = "686e4c9c-f1ab-40ce-8472-cc5d63597263"
  AND filter2.Id = "caa2c2a0-cc5b-42e3-9943-dcda776bdc20"
```

For situations where the order of children is deterministic - you can avoid performing a cross product (`JOIN`) by using the child element's index in the query. This will be faster and cheaper query:

```sql
SELECT p.id
FROM p
WHERE p.Filters[0].Id = "686e4c9c-f1ab-40ce-8472-cc5d63597263"
  AND p.Filters[1].Id = "caa2c2a0-cc5b-42e3-9943-dcda776bdc20"
```